# Add Custom button to Home tab

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am trying to create a button within the default Home tab in Outlook 2010. In VS2010 I added a commandBarButton but it keeps adding to the AddIns tab. I want to display in Home tab.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
Dim newToolBar As Office.CommandBar
Dim firstButton As Office.CommandBarButton
Dim selectExplorers As Outlook.Explorers

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    selectExplorers = Me.Application.Explorers()
    AddHandler selectExplorers.NewExplorer, AddressOf _
        Me.NewExplorer_Event
    AddToolbar()
End Sub

Private Sub NewExplorer_Event(ByVal new_Explorer _
    As Outlook.Explorer)
    new_Explorer.Activate()
    newToolBar = Nothing
    Call Me.AddToolbar()
End Sub

Private Sub AddToolbar()

   Try
        button_1 = CType(newToolBar.Controls.Add(1),  _
            Office.CommandBarButton)
        'button_1.Size = New Size(100, 50)
        'button_1.Size.Height = 42
        With button_1
            '.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption
            .Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle _
            .msoButtonIconAndCaption
            .Caption = "Forward Email to Loop"
            .Height = 80
        End With

        If Me.firstButton Is Nothing Then
            Me.firstButton = button_1
            AddHandler firstButton.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
        End If

        newToolBar.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Outlook 2010, buttons added using the old Explorer.Toolbars collection will be added to the Addins tab (designed specifically for the legacy addins that have not been updated for Outlook 2010).

Buttons can be added to the ribbons only from COM addins. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398246.aspx for more information.